# MALICIOUS_CODE EI_EXPOSE_REP2 may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into MyService.webClient

Tags: java, sonarqube, spring-webclient, spotbugs

What I would like to achieve:

Having a SpringBoot @Service class (called MyService) to send HTTP requests without the SonarQube and SpotBugs flag may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into MyService.webClient

What I tried:

Here is the code

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebClient getWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://somehost.com").build();
    }
```

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

@Autowired
public MyService(WebClient client) {
        this.webClient = client;
    }
```

Issue:

Reproducible 100% of the time, SonarQube and Spotbugs flag this as MALICIOUS_CODE   EI_EXPOSE_REP2  may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into MyService.webClient

Even if I use `WebClient.mutate()`, issue still persists.

Question:

How to fix this vulnerability?